# Datastore google app engine query specific field and without child

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

I try to optimize my GAE.
This is my model :

> Game : id , status, players ... and List ; 
>  Round : id ,
>   name, desc ... ;

I got relationships between Game and Round : **1-N**

The problem is I can't request a Game without his all Round or specific field.

I have already tried this :

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Game.class);
ArrayList<Game> allgame = new ArrayList<Game>();
query.setResult("id, status");
allgame.addAll((Collection<? extends Game>) query.execute());
```

and

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT id, status FROM com.ws.model.Game");
ArrayList<Object> allgame = new ArrayList<Object>();
allgame.addAll((Collection<? extends Object>) query.execute());
```

I'm using the PersistenceManagerFactory and JDO v1.
I really want to reduce my read cost by not request all child (Round)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object is retrieved from the datastore by JDO, only the called ***fetch group***  is retrieved. Unindexed properties including *Text* and *Blob* are not retrieved by default. This means that serialized field values (as your Round objects) will not be retrieved by default. *This is called lazy loading*.*

To get only certain fieds you can use a query like this:

```
        query = pm.newQuery("SELECT status, players FROM " +
                Game.class.getName() + " WHERE xy == :xy);
```

Remember that in this case the fields you retrieve must be indexed.

Hope this helps.

*REF: [Google App Engine Java and GWT Application Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690448)

Comment: Ok it's work.
Now I understand what it's mean FetchGroup.
It was true by default, I change it to False and it's work

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "gameParent", defaultFetchGroup = "false")
    private List<Round> roundList = new ArrayList<Round>();

But now the answer of the query is an Object, How to retrieve field ?

Comment: Exactly. You will have to retrieve the fields manually, something like this: TYPE fieldvalue = listObject.get(0..n)[0..n];
I dont know any fancy way to do it.

Comment: I can't get the data in my Object because I request many fields.